# Filesystem for Gentoo root?

Tags: linux, filesystems, gentoo

I need a fast and space efficient filesystem for my Gentoo workstation.

I have some experience with `ext4` and found it very slow on lots of small files inside the filesystem. I am considering another filesystem, but don't know what to use: suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

"Root FS" alone is quite non-descriptive term since it's unclear will you use another mountpoints and what/where are they.

So, in common — quite space efficient is Btrfs with `compress=lzo` (or even `compress-force=`), and it was mine recent choice for root FS, but mine root FS is read-<strike>only</strike>mostly since I've separate FSes for, say, /home (EXT4) and torrent storage (which used to be XFS, but now is also Btrfs, BTW).

In despite of what your choice would be I strongly encourage you to use LVM-2 since it'd give you flexibility with all those FSes you come along. ;-)

Comment: currently i have separated partitions for home and kvm images storage, i have tried also btrfs, but it degraded veary quickly (after formatting few days it worked really fast, faster than everything, but it "died" in week to ugly state), i using lvm, but now trying raid0 via mdadm instead of lvm (for home fs), works fine, currently i trying jfs for root, i will reply about results in few days

Comment: `btrfs filesystem defragment` to make it alive again? :) LVM is logical volume manager and MD is a block device for it — they're for different purposes and meanwhile these purposes can slightly overlap, you'd better use both since MD has not functions of LVM.

Comment: jfs still works fine after week, i have made few portage syncs, rebuilded (completely removed and copied kernel sources), and made big system upgrade (replace many files)

Comment: @sss123next, jfs is the slowest one.